# How do I transfer a volume's data to another volume on my local host in docker?

Tags: docker, volume

I did

```
docker run -v /jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:alpine
```

on Windows (with docker installed as a linux container).

However, after configuring jenkins on that container, I now wanted to transfer the data in that /jenkins_home volume into a C:\jenkins_home folder on my local windows host machine\another machine.

Any way I can get the data from the /jenkins_home to c:/jenkins_home?

I know I should have made it

```
docker run -v c:/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:alpine
```

at the start but mistakes were made and I was wondering how do I fix that as the above suggestion?

Tried running

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --volumes-from jenkins_old -v c:/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins_new jenkins/jenkins:alpine
```

but it doesn't transfer the data over using the new c:\jenkins_home folder

```
docker run -v /jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:alpine
```

Can't get the data to transfer over from the /jenkins_home folder to c:\jenkins_home folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the /jenkins_home would map to on windows, but you could try this:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /jenkins_home:/from -v c:\jenkins_home:/to alpine cp -r /from /to
```